# get round grand total in cart & invoice

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want a rounding grand total; I have created a custom module and rewritten the core models to achieve this.

My rewrite Model code is below

**1. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand**

```
<?php
class Lr_Roundtotal_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)    
    {        
        $grandTotal     = $address->getGrandTotal();        
        $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();        
        $totals     = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());        
        $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());        
        $address->setGrandTotal(round($grandTotal+$totals)); //Modificated        
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal(round($baseGrandTotal+$baseTotals)); //Modificated        
        //$address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal+$totals);  --Original        
        //$address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal+$baseTotals); --Original        
        return $this;    
    } 

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)    
    {        
        $address->addTotal(array(            
            'code'  => $this->getCode(),            
            'title' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),            
            'value' => round($address->getGrandTotal()),            
            'netvalue' => round($address->getGrandTotal()),            
            'area'  => 'footer',        
        ));                
        return $this;    
    }   
}
```

and second one is

**2.Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice**

```
<?php
    class Lr_Roundtotal_Model_Order_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice
    {
        public function pay()
        {
            if ($this->_wasPayCalled) {
                return $this;
            }
            $this->_wasPayCalled = true;
    
            $invoiceState = self::STATE_PAID;
            if ($this->getOrder()->getPayment()->hasForcedState()) {
                $invoiceState = $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getForcedState();
            }
    
            $this->setState($invoiceState);
    
            $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->pay($this);
            $this->getOrder()->setTotalPaid(
                round($this->getOrder()->getTotalPaid()+$this->getGrandTotal())  //Modificated 
                // $this->getOrder()->getTotalPaid()+$this->getGrandTotal()  --Original
            );
            $this->getOrder()->setBaseTotalPaid(
                round($this->getOrder()->getBaseTotalPaid()+$this->getBaseGrandTotal())  //Modificated 
                // $this->getOrder()->getBaseTotalPaid()+$this->getBaseGrandTotal()  --Original
            );
            Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_invoice_pay', array($this->_eventObject=>$this));
            return $this;
        }   
    }
```

For example

> **Cart**
>
> sub-total  : 990.00
>
> discount   : 120.70
>
> Grand Total: **869.00**(rounded)
>
> **Invoice**
>
> sub-total  : 990.00
>
> discount   : 120.70
>
> Grand Total: **869.30**(not-rounded)

I want same grand total in cart and Invoice

Answer (score 0):

Once you overwrite the core file in local then implement below code.

First create one function in the HELPER file like below(no need to create new module but you can put this function in any module helper file):

```
Namespace_module_helper_data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract 
{
   public function getFormatedPrice($price)     
   {
     return Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format($price, array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), false);    
   } 
}
```

then you can just use this function where you need to round the price in any where in Magento.

You can use helper function like below:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('modulename'); // module name means name of the module in which you have create helper
```

Use function for round price like below:

```
$price = 120.12456;
echo $helper->getFormatedPrice($price); // you can get round price as per your store.
```

Comment: Thanks @Elsner for your answer But, This is not proper way to get round Total in Order or Invoice.

Comment: Your ans is very useful for front-end. This will not work for me because of Changes in many places.